# how to merge two text file and append new value in python

Tags: python

I want to merge two text file and append new values in file using python. I've **file1.txt** and **file2.txt** -  I want to take new value from file **file2.txt** and append to **file1.txt**. If same key is exist in file1.txt - then append new value with existing one or create a new line item.

In this example - I've itemNumber1 and itemNumber2 key in file2.txt. These key is already exist in file1.txt so i've to append new value(file2.tx) to the existing one. It shouldn't overwrite. If any new key is there like itemNumber5 just add new line item like below output.txt.

What's the elegant way of doing this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

**file1.txt**

```
ABC itemNumber1 itemName1,itemModel1,itemPrice1,itemSoldby1|itemName11,itemModel11,itemPrice11,itemSoldby11|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|
ABC itemNumber2 itemName2,itemModel2,itemPrice2,itemSoldby2|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|
ABC itemNumber3 itemName3,itemModel3,itemPrice3,itemSoldby3|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14|
```

**file2.txt**

```
ABC itemNumber1 itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13
ABC itemNumber2 itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14
ABC itemNumber5 itemName5,itemModel5,itemPrice5,itemSoldby5
```

**output.txt**

```
ABC itemNumber1 itemName1,itemModel1,itemPrice1,itemSoldby1|itemName11,itemModel11,itemPrice11,itemSoldby11|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|
ABC itemNumber2 itemName2,itemModel2,itemPrice2,itemSoldby2|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14|
ABC itemNumber3 itemName3,itemModel3,itemPrice3,itemSoldby3|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14|
ABC itemNumber5 itemName5,itemModel5,itemPrice5,itemSoldby5|
```

Comment: This is a fairly broad question... can you elaborate on which step specifically you're having trouble with?

Comment: you want to match only by `itemNumber` ? if `itemNumber` is same then append new value there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with creating your files:

```
with open("file1.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""itemNumber1 itemName1,itemModel1,itemPrice1,itemSoldby1|itemName11,itemModel11,itemPrice11,itemSoldby11|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|
itemNumber2 itemName2,itemModel2,itemPrice2,itemSoldby2|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|
itemNumber3 itemName3,itemModel3,itemPrice3,itemSoldby3|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14|""")

with open("file2.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""itemNumber1 itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13
itemNumber2 itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14
itemNumber5 itemName5,itemModel5,itemPrice5,itemSoldby5""")
```

Now to the actual code:

```
import pandas as pd

files = ["file1.txt","file2.txt"]

# create dataframes
dfs = (pd.read_csv(i,header=None,sep=" ",index_col=0) for i in files)

# concat to one dataframe
df = pd.concat(dfs)

# groupby and sum
df = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x.sum())

# use this if you want to glue them with a string (e.g. |)
# seeing your file.txt ends with | this is not necessary!
# df = df.groupby(df.index)[1].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x)).to_frame()

# output
df.to_csv("output.txt",header=None,sep=" ")
```

Outputs:

```
itemNumber1 itemName1,itemModel1,itemPrice1,itemSoldby1|itemName11,itemModel11,itemPrice11,itemSoldby11|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13
itemNumber2 itemName2,itemModel2,itemPrice2,itemSoldby2|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14
itemNumber3 itemName3,itemModel3,itemPrice3,itemSoldby3|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14|
itemNumber5 itemName5,itemModel5,itemPrice5,itemSoldby5
```

Comment: Thanks, when i try to add some value before my key - your code is breaking. I've updated my post. And will be there any performance impact if I process with 50 millions of line.

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can try with the pythonic way using some list comprehension without using any external lib :

```
with open('jappa.txt','r') as file_a, open('appa.txt','r') as file_b:
    file_1=[item.split() for item in file_b] #storing file_1 content
    file_2=[item.split() for item in file_a] #storing file_2 content


for index,item in enumerate(file_1):
    for index_1,item_1 in enumerate(file_2):
        if item[0]==item_1[0]:  #if If same key is exist
            file_1[index].extend([item_1[1]]) #append new value with existing one
            file_2.pop(index_1)


[file_1.append(rest_of) for rest_of in file_2]
[item.insert(1,' ') for item in file_1]


with open('file_3kare.txt','w+') as file_c:  #writing final result to file_3
    for item in file_1:
        file_c.write("".join(item)+"\n")
```

output in file_3.txt :

```
itemNumber1 itemName1,itemModel1,itemPrice1,itemSoldby1|itemName11,itemModel11,itemPrice11,itemSoldby11|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13
itemNumber2 itemName2,itemModel2,itemPrice2,itemSoldby2|itemName12,itemModel12,itemPrice12,itemSoldby12|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14
itemNumber3 itemName3,itemModel3,itemPrice3,itemSoldby3|itemName13,itemModel13,itemPrice13,itemSoldby13|itemName14,itemModel14,itemPrice14,itemSoldby14|
itemNumber5 itemName5,itemModel5,itemPrice5,itemSoldby5
```

Comment: @Thanks Ayodhyankit. But your code i breaking if I try to add some constant value in front of my key